# How can I target the first four <li>' s in an <ul>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I Have a simple unordered list containing over 12 li's.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to target the first four li's to change their background, and the last four li's to create a different background. Is there any way to do this only with CSS? I know how to use pseudo classes for targeting the first, or the last li, or every forth element, but what I want is to target all first-four, and last-four elements.

Comment: In your posted code you've only got five `li` elements; which means three of those elements will have conflicting requirements, and be targeted by both rules (being within the first four *and* the last four); which rule should take precedence? (I realise you specify 'over twelve' in your question, though.)

Comment: Yes, I only wrote the code to form an idea about the list. I will add though some more elements to avoid confusion. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
ul li:nth-child(-n+4)
```

for the first four, and

```
ul li:nth-last-child(-n+4)
```

for the last four.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. It doesn't work for me right now.

Comment: Sorry about that. It works. Thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

Using `nth-child` is the best practice.

```
li:nth-child(-n+4) {
   background-color:gren;   
}
```

But you **won't get full browser compatibility.**  especially in lower versions of **IE**
If you are using static html, you can create a class and and apply to the first four `li`

eg:

```
.special{
    background-color:gren;
    }


<ul>
    <li class="special"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="special"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="special"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="special"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user **nth-child** and **nth-last-of-type**.

So the CSS code will be :

```
ul li:nth-child(-n+4) {
    background: red;
}

ul li:nth-last-of-type(-n+4) {
    background: blue;
}
```